# How do you inspect and element when right click is disabled and the keyboard shortcuts are too?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web-inspector

I am on http://cloudinternetexplorer.com/ and it won't let me use the keyboard shortcuts or right click. How do I inspect elements on the page?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many different ways to do this...
You have given no detail here as to what you're doing. Are you using IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera? Windows, Mac, Linux? Try `view-source:http://cloudinternetexplorer.com/`? Or here, if you just want the index page, I made a pastebin for you - https://pastebin.com/PRZwUVDw.

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: I wanted to inspect the element. I already did `view-source:http://cloudinternetexplorer.com/` before I asked this question. I wanted to know how to inspect the page.